# Constraint on linear program confusion

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

In a supposed linear program, there exists the following constraint $(x_1+x_3)^2 \ge 16$. Now, does this constraint mean that the program is non-linear? Or is taking a square root permitted here.

Comment: You can derive a linear constraint from it.  Namely $x_1+x_3≥4$ or $x_1+x_3≤-4$.

Comment: @lulu Much appreciated.

Comment: @lulu, sometimes, even one simple answer is good to be added and accepted.